# KeyPressed event for ANY element of a panel

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, enter

So this is my code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
    int keyID = ke.getKeyCode();
    Object o = ke.getSource();

    if (keyID == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        if(o.equals(GUI.btnOK)){
            //Do something
        }
    }}}
```

Ok so what this does is //Do something, when `JButton` called `btnOK` is accessed through key <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The question is: How do I place the `o.equals(GUI.btnOK)` to get triggered by enter when **whatever** element of the main panel is pressed?

It has few things and `btnOK` is one of them. My main panel is:

```
pnlMain= new JPanel(null);
```

I have tried:

```
if (keyID == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            if(o.equals(GUI.pnlMain)){
                //Do something
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to work, despite the fact that I did add the event to the main panel.

EXAMPLE:

```
if (keyID== KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
if(o.equals(GUI.txtLogin) || o.equals(GUI.pwfPWD) || o.equals(GUI.btnOK)){
  //Do this
  igu.setVisible(false);
  igu.dispose();
  System.exit(0); }}
```

In stead of placing all the buttons possible to get triggered by <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> in the `if(o.equals(whatever)|| etc...` I want it to be available (the escape button pressed) for whenever the program is opened wherever the focus is.

Comment: You have: if (keyID == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) and you expect the program to enter that if clause without pressing an ENTER key?

Comment: I want it to "//Do something" wherever I press enter on the element inside the JPanel... change "//DO something" by:     GUI.setVisible(false);
GUI.dispose();
System.exit(0);

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  They sound perfect for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this:

//You can bind key to `JComponent`, So whenever you press `ENTER` on 'JComponent`it does desired operation say Transfer Focus to next`JComponent`, like:

```
jComponent.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
jComponent.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);
```

//You can bind key to JButton, So whenever you press `ENTER` on 'JButton`it does desired operation say Click the`JButton`,  like:

```
jButton.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "DoClick");
jButton.getActionMap().put("DoClick", action);
```

//action

```
AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        button.doClick();        
        } else if(e.getSource() instanceof JComponent){
            JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            component.transferFocus();
        }
    }
    };
```